# Why won't my page reflect the changes I made in my code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to get this simple test to work so I can move on in terms of making a practice web app with ReactJS.

The problem is, every time I make a change, I have to press `cmd + shift + r`and do a hard reload instead of a regular reload (`cmd + r`)

I tried:

Dev tools > Disable Cache (while DevTools is open) but it doesn't work.

On a side note, my server is working fine.  I feel like this issue I'm describing might be a cache issue.

Here's my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>My website</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.16/browser.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here's my `index.js` file:

```
ReactDOM.render(<h1>testin</h1>, document.getElementById('example'));
```

Comment: how are you loading this up, which web server are you using?

Comment: @Rudolf Olah In terminal, I typed: `sudo npm install -g http-server` then after changing directories to my folder of which contains these 2 files I typed: `http-server`

Comment: @chompy Try running it in incognito mode or a different browser? You 100% sure it's browser cache?

Comment: @Devrim yeah it is im 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try running `http-server -c-1` the **-c-1** flag here is supposed to disable caching.

The [http-server command line options](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server#available-options) have some information on the `-c` flag:

> Set cache time (in seconds) for cache-control max-age header, e.g. -c10 for 10 seconds (defaults to '3600'). To disable caching, use -c-1.